# Laravel Model inheritance vs One model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to clean my code and all I have 2 approaches in mind and i want to know what is the best approach 
I have manager model with 3 roles
***Admin  -  Gym_Manager  - City_Manager*** 
First Approach: using one model for all roles but I have to do the same checks

```
    public function revenue($days){
        if ($this->hasRole('gym_manager'))
            return $this->gym->purchases->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays($days))->sum('trainingPackage.price');
        else if ($this->hasRole('city_manager'))
            return $this->city->purchases->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays($days))->sum('trainingPackage.price');
        else
            return Purchase::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays($days))->get()->sum('trainingPackage.price');
    }
```

Second Approach: Having a parent class manager with ***Admin  -  Gym_Manager  - City_Manager***  and applying a global query scope.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Manager extends Model
{

}
class Gym_Manager extends Manager
{

}
class City_Manager extends Manager
{

}
class Admin extends Manager
{

}
```

but I believe I will have the same problem when i try to change role of manager
I will have to cast between models
so is there a better way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you have multiple classes in one file? Anything not working with the first implementation?

Comment: I don't have multiple classes in one file, the first implementation was good until I found out I have to repeat it the check multiple times so I started searching for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first solution, as you dont really save code with the second one. And also using laravel eloquent model, the second solution would make a lot of not that necesary tables.